# React table sorting is not consistent its keep changing back to default state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datatables, signalr, signalr.client

I'm working on this react table sorting when the user clicks on table header it needs to sort the table, sorting is working but the problem is I'm receiving new data every second through SignalR hub and it sets state `udata` to new data. When a user clicks on table header it sorts the table but again goes back to the new state changed by new data. And cancells the sorted table back to unsorted.

Is there any way I can keep sorted state and still receive data?

```
constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
        udata: []
    }

    this.onSort = this.onSort.bind(this)

    let connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
        .withUrl("/signalserver")
        .build();

    connection.start().then(function () {
    }).catch(function (err) {
        return console.error(err.toString());
    });
    connection.on("APIDataChannel", function (data) {
        this.setState({ udata: data });
        // console.log(data);
    }.bind(this));

    async function start() {
        try {
            await connection.start();
            console.log("connected");
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
            setTimeout(() => start(), 5000);
        }
    };

    connection.onclose(async () => {
        await start();
    });

}

renderItem(item, key) {
    const itemRows = [
        <tr onClick={clickCallback} key={"row-data-" + key}>
            <td>{item.appName}</td>
            <td>
                <h6 className="text-muted"><i className={"fa fa-circle text-c-" + (item.appState === 'STARTED' ? 'green' : 'red') + " f-10 m-r-15"} />{item.appState}</h6>
            </td>
            <td>{item.spaceName}</td>
            <td>
                <h6 className="text-muted">{item.orgName}</h6>
            </td>
            <td>
                <h6 className="text-muted">{new Date(item.appUpdatedAt).toLocaleString()}</h6>
            </td>
        </tr>
    ];

    return itemRows;
}


onSort(event, sortKey) {
    const data = this.state.udata;
    data.sort((a, b) => a[sortKey].localeCompare(b[sortKey]))
    this.setState({ data })
}


render() {

    let allItemRows = [];

    this.state.udata.forEach((item, key) => {
        const perItemRows = this.renderItem(item, key);
        allItemRows = allItemRows.concat(perItemRows);
    });

    return (
        <Aux>
            <Row>
                <Table hover responsive>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th onClick={e => this.onSort(e, 'appName')}>App Name</th>
                            <th>State</th>
                            <th>Space</th>
                            <th>Organization</th>
                            <th onClick={e => this.onSort(e, 'appUpdatedAt')}>Updated At</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {allItemRows}
                    </tbody>
                </Table>
            </Row>
        </Aux>
    );
}
```

Comment: do you need to save udata in the state?  I usually store the data outside of it.

Comment: It's not really necessary right now I'm saving data in the state but in the future, I'm planning to use global state, because I have similar 4 pages with different environments. It makes more sense to pull data at one place and then use it all over the application.

Comment: I think you could save the table sort settings in state.  Maybe use those settings to sort udata before saving it to state as well.

Comment: is it possible for you to show me how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I might be able to help more tomorrow.  I'm on a half broken laptop at the moment.

Here's a basic idea, my syntax might be a little off.

```
//might need better default values for sortEvent and sortKey
this.state = {
    udata: [],
    sortEvent: {},
    sortKey: ''
}

connection.on("APIDataChannel", function (data) {
  this.setState({ udata: data });
  // I'm not sure about sortEvent in this context
  onSort(this.state.sortEvent, this.state.sortKey);
  //may need to be a callback like:
  this.setState({ udata: data },onSort(this.state.sortEvent, this.state.sortKey));
   // console.log(data);
}.bind(this));

onSort(event, sortKey, data) {
    this.setState({
      sortEvent: event,
      sortKey: sortKey 
     });
    const data = this.state.udata;
    data.sort((a, b) => a[sortKey].localeCompare(b[sortKey]))
    // I'm not sure what this is doing:
    this.setState({ data })
}

<th onClick={e => this.onSort(e, 'appName', this.state.udata)}>App Name</th>
```

I would also only setState in sort if you end up calling it each time.  Maybe pass data along too.  So:

```
//might need better default values for sortEvent and sortKey
this.state = {
    udata: [],
    sortEvent: {},
    sortKey: ''
}

connection.on("APIDataChannel", function (data) {
  // one onSort call
  onSort(this.state.sortEvent, this.state.sortKey, data);
   // console.log(data);
}.bind(this));

onSort(event, sortKey, data) {
    data.sort((a, b) => a[sortKey].localeCompare(b[sortKey]))
    // Set the state of everything once:
    this.setState({
      sortEvent: event,
      sortKey: sortKey,
      udata: data 
     });
}
<th onClick={e => this.onSort(e, 'appName', this.state.udata)}>App Name</th>
```

I keep double thinking everything.  I really wouldn't save data to state.  Id do:

```
//might need better default values for sortEvent and sortKey
this.state = {
    sortEvent: {},
    sortKey: ''
},
this.data = [];

connection.on("APIDataChannel", function (data) {
  this.data = data;
  // one onSort call
  onSort(this.state.sortEvent, this.state.sortKey);
   // console.log(data);
}.bind(this));

onSort(event, sortKey) {
    this.data.sort((a, b) => a[sortKey].localeCompare(b[sortKey]))
    // Set the state of everything once:
    this.setState({
      sortEvent: event,
      sortKey: sortKey,
      //if you really need to set data to state you could do it here
      udata: data 
     });
}
<th onClick={e => this.onSort(e, 'appName')}>App Name</th>
```

Comment: I tried your solution but I had to click on table header every time page loads to load data.

Comment: @Sam Are there errors? A table without rows? can you log the data and see if it's at least sorted correctly?  I'd also find a way to move your forEach loop out of render.  That's a lot of overhead on render.  I'd look into the component lifecycle: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#the-component-lifecycle

Comment: there are no errors and it is sorting correctly but I have to trigger the event every time by clicking header

Comment: instead of 3 solutions can you post only one clean solution please

Comment: I have to be able to see it render and how.  can you set up a sandbox? https://codesandbox.io/

Comment: I believe that the basic idea of Joe Fitzsimmons that `sortKey` should be stored within `state` object is absolutely correct. The `onSort` should store the sort key value to the state. Something like this: ` this.setState({sortKey})` Then you can use this `state.sortKey` value to sort the data array  passed to your `"APIDataChannel"` event handler before assigning it to `state.udata`.  Meaning that as soon as data has been received they should be sorted with respect to [stored in the state] `sortKey` and only after that assigned to `state.udata`.

Comment: Though the solution with sorting data as soon as they are reloaded (and of course each time the tabel header is clicked) still demonstrates an imperative approach that isn’t encouraged in React. Actually it’s better to store raw [usorted] data in `state.udata` and do actual sorting (again with respect to stored `state.sortKey` value) within `render` method.  If it sounds a bit unclear and complicated I can draft here some POC code that would show the idea by example.